# BJT differential amplifier with active load

Tags: bjt, spice, load, differential-amplifier, falstad

I completed the theoretical parts of the DC and AC analysis. I want to test them with the simulator. Both DC and AC analysis failed.

I killed DC sources in the AC analysis section and I short-circuited the capacitor, but I could not get some output. Can you help?

[image: circuitry]

https://www.falstad.com/circuit/
You can reach my circuitry File -> Import from text

```
$ 1 0.000005 16.817414165184545 50 5 43
t 224 128 176 128 0 -1 0.017928817652922757 3.375077994860476e-14 100
t 336 128 384 128 0 -1 -0.010487543627668239 3.375077994860476e-14 100
t 272 192 304 192 0 -1 0 0 100
t 128 304 176 304 0 1 -0.9318175240468922 -0.9602336107450244 100
t 432 304 384 304 0 1 0.017928809319767702 0.017929083902226473 100
i 288 400 288 448 0 0.0004
w 176 288 176 144 0
w 272 192 176 192 0
w 304 176 304 128 0
w 224 128 336 128 0
w 176 112 176 80 0
w 384 112 384 80 0
w 176 80 384 80 0
w 384 144 384 288 0
w 176 320 176 368 0
w 176 368 384 368 0
w 384 320 384 368 0
w 288 400 288 368 0
w 288 80 288 32 0
w 304 208 304 256 0
R 288 32 288 0 0 0 40 3.3 0 0 0.5
R 288 448 288 496 0 0 40 -3.3 0 0 0.5
R 304 256 304 288 0 0 40 -3.3 0 0 0.5
w 384 192 448 192 0
c 448 192 496 192 0 0.000001 0
r 560 96 560 176 0 720000
w 560 176 560 192 0
g 560 96 560 64 0
g 48 304 48 336 0
w 496 192 560 192 0
O 560 192 624 192 0
v 432 304 512 304 0 1 40 1 0 0 0.5
g 512 304 512 336 0
v 128 304 48 304 0 1 40 1 0 0 0.5
o 25 64 0 4099 0.0000762939453125 0.00009765625 0 2 25 3
o 30 64 0 4098 0.0000762939453125 0.1 1 1
```

Comment: You must keep the dc sources for a proper operating point. You can couple your signal through a bias T (inductor and capacitor).

Comment: Hasan, in the circuit as shown where in the heck is the DC current imbalance supposed to go in your circuit??? There's a darned capacitor in the way of it. You've got a current mirror load in there trying to force equal currents and, separately, a long-tailed pair trying to force a differential current in its collector loads. This is like the unstoppable meeting up with the unmovable. Something is going to break. You do mention something about shorting the capacitor, but no details about that experience. With a DC path, some sense can be made.

Comment: Thank you for both :) my problem is I could not stabilize DC balance. I took the values from the electronics book. I can remove the capacitor if It is the problem. Can you help me to find the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the red dots.  They are NOT connections in falstad.

To fix, highlight underlying wire and press [Ctrl] + [LMB] to create a node.  If it works, the red dots will turn green or white.

Alternatively, use [w] and [space] to move nodes and add wires and connect red nodes to other nodes.  Best to move end of wire to red node and add a second wire from red node (which should be white) to disconnected node.

Or copy corrected txt file below or follow this [link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0lwrOATLekmQMwA4xKQCxjYCciaIiBmlApgLRhgBQY8E2B24BBIJSbmF5QQSSpVbsQAdnjiwANkghsmBctHiV8ZgHdV68Js5DNkfaq7Jup8HijMAxrMVCHb99qiw4cCATQJDLEMgLwmOhwNDD%20zABOVl5JINYqYH5wljJu9uJ2TNoJIIoE6R5lqdzpmRYGnnkllYWOBnbWpSppzrKQfBjcMn08fCqxmRD0mNBIaDIE8LyQJATBCz5xBnIKIkN8wqOWAkIiK-sidfwiB1f9kNVHIgOy8mL3rS-iz9vgOY6JexGTXSF0otUunSBkJal0Bz0hzwhzU00IuzAA5r07oNhvhRo4AErAqrEsaiSqIMkwXRKcRnIEZd43cQAE1oADMAIYAVwANgAXei82gs8CiMawFiYxknfZwIR-MZSEjEpQqaECLQ1cF%20SwI94aooGRb9GTiE2-RQfC1gP6KQiWxxKPiKeBW9Tqs0gD0lG7VcUBqkgLm8gDOtEJJWw3BwLujqSMKnEFMD0F09Uqsyt0aTbo%20JAcsdu3s4%20ZERfpWadrwRXvgfyQXqTEnTxME3Aa7etDbrTybj2xxarlxzYjzlbzFgA9uB1fiyiQhBKIM2Mt7mEA).

[image]

```
$ 1 0.000005 16.817414165184545 50 5 43 5e-11
t 224 128 176 128 0 -1 0.45224417361820635 -0.553686073542238 100 default
t 336 128 384 128 0 -1 2.432680390175281 -0.553686073542238 100 default
t 272 192 304 192 0 -1 5.594069752839555 -0.45224417361820635 100 default
t 128 304 176 304 0 1 -1.604955944453068 0.5536911937616704 100 default
t 432 304 384 304 0 1 0.3754802721040066 0.5536911937616704 100 default
i 288 400 288 448 0 0.0004
w 176 288 176 192 0
w 272 192 176 192 0
w 304 176 304 128 0
w 224 128 304 128 0
w 176 112 176 80 0
w 384 112 384 80 0
w 176 80 288 80 0
w 384 144 384 192 0
w 176 320 176 368 0
w 176 368 288 368 0
w 384 320 384 368 0
w 288 400 288 368 0
w 288 80 288 32 0
w 304 208 304 256 0
R 288 32 288 0 0 0 40 3.3 0 0 0.5
R 288 448 288 496 0 0 40 -3.3 0 0 0.5
R 304 256 304 288 0 0 40 -3.3 0 0 0.5
w 384 192 448 192 0
c 448 192 496 192 0 0.000001 0.05147512605267024 0.001
r 560 96 560 176 0 720000
w 560 176 560 192 0
g 560 96 560 64 0 0
g 48 304 48 336 0 0
w 496 192 560 192 0
O 560 192 624 192 0 0
v 432 304 512 304 0 1 40 1 0 0 0.5
g 512 304 512 336 0 0
v 128 304 48 304 0 1 40 1 0 0 0.5
w 176 192 176 144 0
w 288 80 384 80 0
w 384 192 384 288 0
w 304 128 336 128 0
w 288 368 384 368 0
o 25 64 0 4099 0.625 0.00009765625 0 2 25 3
o 30 64 0 4098 0.625 0.1 1 1
```